# handle MediaElement events like MediaOpened, BufferingStarted with MVVM pattern?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mediaelement

I have done many searches and cannot find a sample on how to do this.

The goal is to handle these events in the view model while avoiding code in the code behind the view. Sample code and XAML would be appreciated. If your solution requires the use of an external DLL please provide source code.

The view model should compile independent of the existence of any View.

Actually, I'm not sure this can be done. Any insight on this issue is welcome.

See sample code on progress so far.

http://database.hugetiger.com/dbExplore/MVVMCode.aspx

Currently mediaopend event msgbox comes from code behind. How can this be modified so that msgbox comes from the MyViewModel class?

Comment: What are you planning to do within the events?

Comment: update a lable on the view and update the state in the model

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the `System.Windows.Interactivity` and `Microsoft.Expression.Interactions` combo will be perfect for your needs.

In this example we use `System.Windows.Interactivity` `EventTrigger` on the `MediaElement` `BufferingStarted` event to change a property and call a method on the model using `Microsoft.Expression.Interactions` methods

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication14.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
            xmlns:expint="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
            xmlns:sysint="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity">
        <Grid>
            <MediaElement >
                <sysint:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <sysint:EventTrigger EventName="BufferingStarted" >
                        <expint:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="MyProperty" Value="NeValue" />
                        <expint:CallMethodAction  MethodName="MyModelMethod"/>
                    </sysint:EventTrigger>
                </sysint:Interaction.Triggers>
            </MediaElement>
        </Grid>
    </Window>
```

Yuo will have to add a reference to `System.Windows.Interactivity` and `Microsoft.Expression.Interactions` dll's.
The `Microsoft.Expression.Interactions` is part of the [ExpressionBlend SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10801)

Hope this helps as I have found this combo amazing for WPF development.

Happy Coding :)

Comment: void OnBufferingStarted(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)

Comment: I got ExpressionBlend SDK installed and put in references to System.Windows.Interactivity and Microsoft.Expression.Interactions. Event BufferingStarted takes a method with args: void OnBufferingStarted(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) this method is in class VideoViewModel namespace ViewModel. How should the xaml be improved to hook up the method?

Comment: Why do you need the eventargs, I thought you were just updating a lable and a state in the model, what do you need out of the event args that you cant get via the MediaElement object in your Xaml?

Comment: I don't need the event args, I'm still unclear on how to hook up the event, to a event handler.

Comment: There is no event handler, when the event BufferingStarted is fired it activates the trigger, Experssion.Interactions allows you to call methods, change properties etc, You can call any of your methods in your model, This thread here may explain a bit more http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/wpf/thread/415706c8-9837-4745-baca-7367e194b44b

Comment: I looked at the link from your post and got it to run. It was easy because both the xaml and C# code were there.

It is triggered by a dependency property. I have no problem using the MVVM pattern with dependency properties. Dependency properties have the wrench icon associated with them in VS2012. Whereas, events such as  BufferingStarted, MediaEnded have the lightning icon.

Currently, mediaopened msg comes from the code behind, How do I modify this code so that it comes from the MyViewModel class

Here the code I have so far:
http://database.hugetiger.com/dbExplore/MVVMCode.aspx